# MQ (from an iSeries) and Delphi

Tags: delphi, ibm-midrange, ibm-mq

Has anyone had any experience of talking between an iSeries (using IBM's Websphere MQ) and PC code - hopefully using Delphi 2009.

**Modification:**

I have a large PC based program (that talks to an iSeries) that I need to rewrite. One option would be to do most of the tricky and processor intensive processing on the iSeries and then have that program signal the PC based program (written in Delphi at the moment) to do the part of the processing that are best done on the PC. So I need to signal the final part somehow from the iSeries, without it polling the iSeries all the time.

Comment: I developed a lot of code for iSeries from PC/D2007/2009. What specifically did you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried to get it to work, but this looks interesting - http://jamiei.com/blog/2009/02/Delphi-mqtt-client/

Answer (score 1):

First option: add a Java app to the Delphi side which uses a JMS client to listen to an event topic on the MQ server, which receives a `complete` message from the worker process and forwards this message to the Delphi app (over TCP/IP or other simple IPC methods).

Second option: implement a simple web service server in the Delphi app which has only one method `notify()` and call this service from the WebSphere side. An example for a stand-alone SOAP server for Delphi 7 (but can be modified to work with D2009 too) using Indy can be found [here](http://www.digicoast.com/delphi_soap_standalone.html).